# JQuery No Conflict does not work

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, joomla3.0

JQuery No Conflict does not work

Please refer this link - http://www.guru99.com/accounting.html

Please refer this exercise -  http://screencast.com/t/0wt2L8pD2Yc

When I put the code in a single article, it works

But does not work with other Jquery code. I used Jquery no confloct with zero effect

Please Guide

The code I am using is

```
(function(jQuery) {      jQuery(document).ready(function(){

     jQuery(document).ready(function(){
     jQuery("#Assets").keyup(function(){
        jQuery("#Assets").blur();
        jQuery("#Assets").focus(); });


    jQuery("#Assets").change(function(){
        var assetname = document.getElementById('Assets').value;

        assetname = jQuery.trim(assetname);
      if(assetname.match(/cake/gi))
      {
        jQuery('#message1').show();
         jQuery('#e1').hide();
      }
        else
        {
            jQuery('#message1').hide();
             jQuery('#e1').show();

        } });




    jQuery('input.obadd').click(function () {
    jQuery('input.obadd:checked').not(this).removeAttr('checked');
     var sFilter = "";
    jQuery('input.obadd[type=checkbox]').each(function () {
        sFilter = sFilter + (this.checked ? jQuery(this).val() : "");
    });
    if(sFilter=='22')
    {

        jQuery('#message2').show();
         jQuery('#e2').hide();
    }
    else if(sFilter=='')
    {

        jQuery('#e2').hide();
        jQuery('#message2').hide();
    }    else    {
        jQuery('#message2').hide();
         jQuery('#e2').show();
    } });


      jQuery('input.obadd1').click(function () {
    jQuery('input.obadd1:checked').not(this).removeAttr('checked');
     var sFilter = "";
    jQuery('input.obadd1[type=checkbox]').each(function () {
        sFilter = sFilter + (this.checked ? jQuery(this).val() : "");
    });
    if(sFilter=='2')
    {

        jQuery('#message3').show();
         jQuery('#e3').hide();
    }
    else if(sFilter=='')
    {

        jQuery('#e3').hide();
        jQuery('#message3').hide();
    }    else    {
        jQuery('#message3').hide();
         jQuery('#e3').show();
    } });

     jQuery("#text1").keyup(function(){
        jQuery("#text1").blur();
        jQuery("#text1").focus();
     });


    jQuery("#text1").change(function(){
        var assetname = document.getElementById('text1').value;
    var assetname = document.getElementById('text1').value;
      assetname = jQuery.trim(assetname);
      if(assetname.match(/21650/gi))
      {
        jQuery('#message4').show();
         jQuery('#e4').hide();
      }
      else if(assetname.match(/21,650/gi))
      {
        jQuery('#message4').show();
         jQuery('#e4').hide();
      }
        else
        {
            jQuery('#message4').hide();
             jQuery('#e4').show();

        }
    });



       jQuery('input.obadd3').click(function () {
    jQuery('input.obadd3:checked').not(this).removeAttr('checked');
     var sFilter = "";
    jQuery('input.obadd3[type=checkbox]').each(function () {
        sFilter = sFilter + (this.checked ? jQuery(this).val() : "");
    });
    if(sFilter=='2')
    {

        jQuery('#message5').show();
         jQuery('#e5').hide();
    }
    else if(sFilter=='')
    {

        jQuery('#e5').hide();
        jQuery('#message5').hide();
    }    else    {
        jQuery('#message5').hide();
         jQuery('#e5').show();
    } });


     jQuery("#text2").keyup(function(){
        jQuery("#text2").blur();
        jQuery("#text2").focus();
     });   
     jQuery("#text2").change(function(){
        var assetname = document.getElementById('text2').value;
    var assetname = document.getElementById('text2').value;
      assetname = jQuery.trim(assetname);
      if(assetname.match(/2600/gi))
      {
        jQuery('#message6').show();
         jQuery('#e6').hide();
      }
        else
        {
            jQuery('#message6').hide();
             jQuery('#e6').show();

        }
    });


     });    });    })(jQuery);
```

Comment: if u can create jsfiddle having your html and js files with their respective code please.